# Changing onclick attribute using replace with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, replace, onclick, attr

Do someone know what is the best way to replace some string inside a onclick attribute ?

**I need to get the current value** and replace some text inside parameters.

**Exemple, 
I have this link:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('parameter1a','parameter1b')">My link</a>
```

**And I want this:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction('parameter2a','parameter2b')">My link</a>
```

**In other words, I want something like this:**

```
$('a').attr('onclick', $(this).attr('onclick').replace('1', '2'));
```

**And I know I can do this, but I need something dynamic retreiving the values of current element:**

```
$("a").attr('onClick', "myfunction('parameter2a','parameter2b')");
```

Finally it working when I made a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GkWhh/4/

Thank you for your solutions !

Comment: Why do you "need something more dynamic?"

Comment: You just need to know what the paramters are you need to change and create a conditional statement within the click function to pass the parameters to your custom `myFunction(par1, par2)`

Comment: Why do you need to do this in first place? How is this layout being created and why can't you change it? Overall, this is a wrong approach

Comment: @Alexander - Do you have a better approach ?

Comment: I made a simple demo on jsFiddle. But finally it working! I will look closer to my real code to see what is missing. Before, when I added some objectives ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GkWhh/4/)) the link to add Solution didnt update the parameters. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('a[onclick]').attr('onclick', function(i, v){
   return v.replace(/1/g, '2');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cj9j7/

If you need something more dynamic do not use `onclick` attributes, changing `onclick` attributes is *hackish*, you can use `click` method instead.

```
var param = 1;
$('a').click(function(){
   // ...

   if ('wildguess') {
     param = 1;
   } else {
     param++;
   }
})
```

Comment: I would also change the selector to `a[onclick]`

Comment: It is weird, I see that it's working on your jsFiddle.

But for me the console show me : Uncaught TypeError: Object function onclick(event) {
  myfunction('parameter1a','parameter1b')
} has no method 'replace'

Comment: @ShadGagnon That's because some of your `a` elements don't have `onclick` attributes, I have updated the selector.

Comment: I have updated the selector... But the problem is still here. I tried to alert the onclick attr like this **alert($(this).attr('onclick'))** before the **return v.replace(/1/g, '2')** and it show me my function correctly. The console still show : 
Uncaught TypeError: Object function onclick(event) {
  myfunction('parameter1a','parameter1b'
} has no method 'replace'

Comment: @ShadGagnon Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I made a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GkWhh/2/) on jsFiddle.
But finally it working! I will look closer to my real code to see what is missing. Before, when I added some objectives ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GkWhh/2/)) the link to add Solution didnt update the parameters. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a really bad idea but anyway - you can access the string value of the onlick attribute using something like that:

`$('a').each(function() { this.attributes.onclick.nodeValue =  this.attributes.onclick.nodeValue.replace('1', '2'); })`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/SJP7k/

```
var atr = $('a').attr('onclick');
var str = atr.split('1');
var natr = str.join('2');
$('a').attr('onclick',natr);
```