# Change html onclick value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to find and replace a piece of text in an `onCLick` event in the DOM. I tried jQuery `find` `contains` and may more but none of them worked. Can you please help. There are multiple onClick events with the same 'class' so I want to first look for `Click OK to cancel this booking.` and THEN replace it with `he New Piece Of Text Here'

**This is what I have**

```
`<a href="#" class="replaced_btn" onclick="return confirm('Click OK to cancel this booking.');"></a>`
```

**I want it changed to this**
    `<a href="#" class="replaced_btn" onclick="return confirm('The New Piece Of Text Here');"></a>`

Comment: Can't you just change the html ?

Comment: No. This is dynamically generated from another js file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365731/changing-onclick-attribute-using-replace-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [attribute contains filter](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```js
jQuery('.replaced_btn[onclick*="Click OK to cancel this booking."]').attr('onclick', function(i, value) {
  return value.replace('Click OK to cancel this booking.', 'The New Piece Of Text Here')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="replaced_btn" onclick="return confirm('Click OK to cancel this booking.');">test</a>
```

or [attribute equals](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
jQuery('.replaced_btn[onclick="return confirm(\'Click OK to cancel this booking.\');"]').attr('onclick', function(i, value) {
  return value.replace('Click OK to cancel this booking.', 'The New Piece Of Text Here')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="replaced_btn" onclick="return confirm('Click OK to cancel this booking.');">test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elem = '<a href="#" class="replaced_btn" onclick="return confirm(' + 'Click OK to cancel this booking.' + ');"></a>';
elem = elem.replace("Click OK to cancel this booking.", "The New Piece Of Text Here");
alert(elem)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**OR**

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var elem = $(this).attr('onclick');
  elem = elem.replace("Click OK to cancel this booking.", "The New Piece Of Text Here");
  $(this).attr('onclick',elem);
  alert($(this).attr('onclick'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="replaced_btn" onclick="return confirm(' + 'Click OK to cancel this booking.' + ');"> Test </a>
```